# How to get fields of a Julia object

Tags: object, types, field, julia

Given a Julia object of composite type, how can one determine its fields?

I know one solution if you're working in the REPL: First you figure out the type of the object via a call to `typeof`, then enter help mode (`?`), and then look up the type.  Is there a more programmatic way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: a hack that I use: at the REPL, for object `x`, type `x.` (that's `x` followed by a dot `.`) and then hit TAB once or twice. that asks Julia to autocomplete the command. Julia will then show you the fields of `x`, assuming that it has any.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**For v0.7+**

Use `fieldnames(x)`, where `x` is a `DataType`. For example, use `fieldnames(Date)`, *instead of* `fieldnames(today())`, or else use `fieldnames(typeof(today()))`.

This returns `Vector{Symbol}` listing the field names in order.

If a field name is `myfield`, then to retrieve the values in that field use either `getfield(x, :myfield)`, or the shortcut syntax `x.myfield`.

Another useful and related function to play around with is `dump(x)`.

**Before v0.7**

Use `fieldnames(x)`, where `x` is either an instance of the composite type you are interested in, or else a `DataType`. That is, `fieldnames(today())` and `fieldnames(Date)` are equally valid and have the same output.

Comment: If I get the first field of a Struct: `fieldnames(s)[1]` that will be a Symbol. But I cannot use the result of this expression to get the value of that field like: `s.fieldnames(s)[1]` although s.:field works.
`getfield` works as expected.

Comment: `s.fieldnames(s)[1]`, roughly speaking, parses to: find the field literally named `fieldnames` in `s`, and then call it as if it is a function with `(s)` as argument, and then get the first element of the result, ie `[1]` (which is obviously not what you are trying to do). If you have the actual fieldname stored in some symbol `a`, then use `getfield(s, a)`. It is true that `s.:a` also works, but this is not idiomatic Julia, so others will probably have a hard time reading your code. I've updated my answer to try and clear up any ambiguity.

Comment: above link is broken

Comment: @liang [updated link](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/reflection/)

Comment: N.b. if you want the types of the fields, `fieldtypes(T)`. And if you want both the field names and their types, `NamedTuple{fieldnames(T)}(fieldtypes(T))`, which for `Rational` would give `(num = Integer, den = Integer)`.

Answer (score 8):

suppose the object is `obj`,

you can get all the information of its fields with following code snippet:

```
T = typeof(obj)
for (name, typ) in zip(fieldnames(T), T.types)
    println("type of the fieldname $name is $typ")
end
```

Here, `fieldnames(T)` returns the vector of field names and `T.types` returns the corresponding vector of type of the fields.