# fieldnames(x::DataType) does not work in Julia 1.0.1

Tags: julia

I have a composite type, `MyType`,

```
 struct MyType

 a::Float64
 b::Float64     

 end
```

When I do

```
 a = MyType(1,2)
 fieldnames(a)
```

I get an error

```
 MethodError: no method matching fieldnames(::MyType)
```

When I do

```
 fieldnames(MyType)
```

it returns

```
 (:a,:b)
```

as expected. It was my understanding that the former should work as well - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The behavior was changed in Julia 1.0 and now `fieldnames` works only on data types.

Comment: [Partial duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687418/how-to-get-fields-of-a-julia-object/41687640#41687640)

Comment: I see. I could only find documentation that claimed it would work. Easy workaround is just `fieldnames(typeof(a))`

Comment: just a curiosity, where did you read about it? In general, you should consult resources dealing with Julia >= 1.0, everything before is prehistory...

Answer (score 1):

`fieldnames` was changed with Julia 1.0 to accept only types as its argument. The [NEWS.md](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.7/NEWS.md#deprecated-or-removed) for 0.7 (which was the 1.0-gateway version) mentions that:

> `fieldnames` now operates only on types. To get the names of fields in an object, use `fieldnames(typeof(x))`

The [reasoning](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22350) is essentially two-fold: (1) if it accepts both objects and types, there's an ambiguity since types are *also* objects themselves (so there's an artificial distinction in the old behaviour) (2) the fields are semantically an attribute of the type, not of its individual instances, so it makes more sense to have `fieldnames` operate on types only.